# Excel autofill with letters and numbers

Tags: excel

In excel I would like to auto fill with this pattern

```
R1a
R1b
R1c
R2a
R2b
R2c
R3a
```

ECT.  Any ideal How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter version, in Row1 and copied down to suit:

```
="R"&INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1&CHAR(97+MOD(ROW()+2,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `R1a` in the A1:

Then in A2:

```
="R" &MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)+ IF(MOD(ROW(1:1),3)=0,1,0) & CHOOSE(MOD(ROW(2:2)-1,3)+1,"a","b","c")
```

Then copy/drag down.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMh]